# I need to get function calc_date_number to perform and equation and then use that function equation in main on the dates from the user

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
long int calc_date_number (int, int, int);

main()
{

    int          x, y, month, day, year, invalid_date;
    int          daysPerMonth[12] = {31, y, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    long int     N;

    printf ("Welcome to the Date to Day-of-Week program.\n\n");
    printf ("The program will five the day of the week for any date from 1/1/1900");

    for (x = 0; x < 1; x++)
    {
        printf ("\n\nEnter date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        scanf ("%i/%i/%i", &month, &day, &year);

        daysPerMonth[2] = 28;
        if ( (year % 400 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
            daysPerMonth[2] = 29; 
        else if ( day < 1 || day > daysPerMonth[month - 1]){                 
            printf ("Invalid day. Please re-enter date.\n");
            &invalid_date;
            --x;
            continue;}
        else if ( month < 1 || month > 12){
            printf ("Invalid month. Please re-enter date.\n");
            &invalid_date; 
            --x;
            continue;}
        else if ( year < 1900){
            printf ("Invalid year. Pleas re-enter date.\n");
            &invalid_date;
            --x;
            continue;}
    }
    N = calc_date_number(month, day, year);
    printf("%li", N);

}

long int calc_date_number (int m, int d, int y)
{

    int        f, g;
    long int   date_number;

    if ( m <= 2)
        f == y;
        else 
        f == y;

    if ( m <= 2)
        g == m + 13;
        else
        g == m + 1;

    date_number = (1461 * f)/ 4 + (153 * g) / 5 + d;

return date_number;
```

I cant get main to perform the equation in calc_date_number as my teacher asks.

Comment: Not sure if edit problem, but you are missing final } in calc_date_number

Comment: "I cant get main to perform the equation in calc_date_number as my teacher asks". Why not? Is there an error? Is there incorrect output? Does the program crash? Does the code not compile? Please be specific. Include the expected output/behaviour and the actual output/behaviour.

Comment: `daysPerMonth[2] = 28;` --> `daysPerMonth[1/* 2-1 */] = 28;` because 0 origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in this code. Seems that you are new to C, so I'll illustrate them in detail. However, logical problems are left to you. *user1683793*'s answer can help you to deal with them.

## Inside main()

```
int          daysPerMonth[12] = {31, y, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
```

You are trying to initialize a variable(`dayPermonth[1]`) with another uninitialized variable(`y`). This does not make sense. Just write `{31, 28, 31, 30, ...}`.

---

```
printf ("The program will five the day of the week for any date from 1/1/1900");
```

Perhaps there is a typo here, do you mean "find the day"?

---

```
scanf ("%i/%i/%i", &month, &day, &year);
```

Here is a potential problem: You've told users to enter date in the format of (mm/dd/yyyy). But if I enter `09/08/2016`, the program will judge 09 and 08 as octal numbers due to the preceding zeros. However, digit 8 and 9 should never be in an octal number, so something expected will happen. You can simply change this line to

```
scanf ("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);
```

to fix this.

---

```
daysPerMonth[2] = 28;
```

In C, arrays indexes start with 0. So you have 12 elements in `daysPerMonth`: `daysPerMonth[0]`, `daysPerMonth[1]`, ... `daysPerMonth[11]`. So `daysPerMonth[1]` stands for February. However, if you've written `{31, y, 31, ...}`, the assignment does not make any difference, so it can be removed.

---

```
if ( (year % 400 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
```

According to the definition of a leap year, it should be:

```
if ( (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
```

---

```
daysPerMonth[2] = 29;
```

should be

```
daysPerMonth[1] = 29;
```

for the reason mentioned above. Same problems will not be described hereafter for the sake of brevity.

---

```
else if ( day < 1 || day > daysPerMonth[month - 1]){
```

There shouldn't be an `else`, because even the year entered is a leap year, the day entered can also be invalid. For example, `"00/00/2000"`.

---

```
&invalid_date;
```

This statement is an expression without any side effects. Since it doesn't make any difference, let's remove it.

---

```
printf("%li", N);
```

To print a `long int`, use `"%l"`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ for details.

## Inside calc_date_number()

```
if ( m <= 2)
        f == y;
else
        f == y;

if ( m <= 2)
        g == m + 13;
else
        g == m + 1;
```

These statements does not make any difference, they compare values and do nothing. To assign the value `y` contains to `f`, write `f = y;`. Further more, the two branches of the first if statement are identical, so that if statement doesn't make sense.

---

```
date_number = (1461 * f)/ 4 + (153 * g) / 5 + d;
```

To understand this one, you have to think about the logic carefully. Good luck. I'm going point out that even if it's logically correct, it should be something like `date_number = (1461 * (long int)f)/ 4 + (153 * (long int)g) / 5 + (long int)d;`  or `date_number = (1461L * f)/ 4L + (153L * g) / 5L + d;`  because `int` * `int` = `int`. To get a `long`, you can either cast explicitly or implicitly put some `long`s in the expression. Also note the fact that 3 / 2 = 1, because `3` and `2` are `int`s.

Comment: I am new to C and i'm doing online courses so my teacher takes awhile to get back. Thank you so much this helped me out so much and made me understand it as well

Answer (score 1):

Two problems I see right away in your if statements here are:

1. You're using `==` (the equivalence operator) instead of `=` (the assignment operator).
2. This seems to be more of a logic error, but your first if statement evaluates to the same thing independent of whether m is greater than 2 or not.

   ```
   if ( m <= 2)
       f == y;
       else 
       f == y;

   if ( m <= 2)
       g == m + 13;
       else
       g == m + 1;
   ```

You can also combine these two if statements together since the condition is the same (unless this is a logic error as well). Then all in all the above segment would look like this:

```
if (m <= 2) {
    f = y;
    g = m + 13;
} else {
    f = ? // Replace ? with your value, or remove it, or do whatever
    g = m + 1;
}
```

I could help you more by looking into the logic, but maybe that's not what your teacher would want. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me, I appreciate it so much

Answer (score 1):

I see what is going on.  Your formula computes something like the Julian date and can be used to calculate the difference between two days and if you do it right, you can calculate the day of the week.

I cooked your subroutine a little to be more useful:

```
long int calc_date_number (int m, int d, int y)
{

    int        f, g;
    long int   date_number;

    if ( m <= 2)
        f = y-1;
    else
        f = y;

    if ( m <= 2)
        g = m + 13;
    else
        g = m + 1;

    date_number = (1461 * f)/ 4 + (153 * g) / 5 + d;   /* Find a julian style date */
    date_number -=694404;                              /* Find subtract the offset for 1/1/1901*/
    date_number+=2;                                    /* 1/1/1901 was Tuesday so add 2 */
    date_number %=7;                                   /* Find the day of the week */

    return date_number;
}
```

Incidentally, something to keep in mind, 1900 was not a leap year so if you back this up to 1/1/1900 rather than 1901, it will be off a day.

Comment: Thank you so much, i honestly appreciate this so much, this helped me so much.